# adobe AIR ANE loading screen dialogue for ios

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air-native-extension

I have been searching a lot but with no result
Does any one know of an adobe air native extension for displaying the native loading screen on ios devices?
I came across this one   [a link](http://myappsnippet.com/loading-dialog-air-extension/)  but it only supports android

thanks a lot in advance!!:)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Dialog ANE has progress dialogs for Android and iOS:

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Dialog